# Start omxplayer on startup with user input

Tags: boot, omxplayer

I am having trouble getting omxplayer to automatically play a video after a small delay after powerup, AND be able to use the keyboard controls.

I am adding the omxplayer command to the /etc/rc.local to play a video immediately after boot, but none of the keyboard inputs will work.

I think it has to do with the /etc/rc.local not having "scope" or something to the terminal. I tried calling the omxplayer command from `lxterminal -e` but this never seems to start the playback.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is linked to [Auto-login into LXDE and auto-start video-player (omxplayer)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/auto-login-into-lxde-and-auto-start-video-player-omxplayer/43350) which gives the answer:

```
lxterminal -e "omxplayer -b --loop --no-osd /home/pi/Videos/MyVideoFile.mp4"
```

This has always worked well on Jessie, but I get what you describe when I try this on Stretch. The solution appears to be adding the -l (login shell option)

```
lxterminal -l -e "omxplayer -b --loop --no-osd /home/pi/Videos/MyVideoFile.mp4"
```